# evaluation of $\int\frac{1}{(1+x)(2+x)^2(3+x)^3}dx$

Tags: calculus

Evaluation of $\displaystyle \int\frac{1}{(1+x)(2+x)^2(3+x)^3}dx$

$\bf{My\; Trial \; Solution::}$ Given $\displaystyle \int\frac{1}{(1+x)(2+x)^2(3+x)^3}dx\;\;\;,$ Let $(3+x)=y\;,$ Then $dx = dy$

So Integral Convert into $\displaystyle \int\frac{1}{(y-2)(y-1)^2y^3}dy\;\;,$ Now Let $\displaystyle y = \frac{1}{z}\;\;,$ Then $\displaystyle dy = -\frac{1}{z^2}dz$

So Integral convert into $\displaystyle \int\frac{z^6}{(2z-1)(z-1)^2}\cdot \frac{1}{z^2}dz = \int\frac{z^4}{(2z-1)(z-1)^2}dz$

Now How can I solve after that

Help Required

Thanks

Comment: I think that you have to use partial fraction decomposition of the initial rational function.

Comment: look at : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition

Comment: Partial fraction decomposition is the ONLY way.

Answer (score 6):

Use partial fraction decomposition to decompose the expression into (I used the [Wolf](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=partial%20fraction%201%20/%20%28%281%20%2b%20x%29%282%20%2b%20x%29%5E2%283%20%2b%20x%29%5E3%29)):
$$\frac{1}{(x+1) (x+2)^2 (x+3)^3} = \frac{2}{x+2}-\frac{17}{8}\frac{1}{x+3}-\frac{1}{(x+2)^2}-\frac{5}{4}\frac{1}{(x+3)^2}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{(x+3)^3}+ \frac{1}{8}\frac{1}{x+1}$$

and then integrate directly.

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{1}{(1+x)(2+x)^2(3+x)^3}=\frac{A}{1+x}+\frac{B}{2+x}+\frac{C}{(2+x)^2}+\frac{D}{3+x}+\frac{E}{(3+x)^2}+\frac{F}{(3+x)^3}$